# Group selected data from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, grouping, jupyter

I have a dataframe with that looks like this:

```
   CARD     CALL        COD_DAY
0   5713    0.0         20200716
1   5713    1.0         20200811
2   5713    2.0         20200620
3   5713    3.0         20200619
4   5713    4.0         20200601
... ... ... ...
2135283 73306036    0.0     20200930
2135284 73306055    12.0    20200930
2135285 73306479    9.0     20200930
2135286 73306656    3.0     20200930
2135287 73306676    1.0     20200930
```

I want to select only the CARD that has the highest COD_DAY and CALL is bigger than zero.
I tried a couple of approaches with groupby but no positive result.

Any help much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first filter positive values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and then get rows with maximum `COD_DAY` per `CARD` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices and last pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df[df['CALL'].gt(0)].groupby('CARD')['COD_DAY'].idxmax()]
print (df)
             CARD  CALL   COD_DAY
1            5713   1.0  20200811
2135284  73306055  12.0  20200930
2135285  73306479   9.0  20200930
2135286  73306656   3.0  20200930
2135287  73306676   1.0  20200930
```

If need one card not per groups:

```
card = df.loc[df.loc[df['CALL'].gt(0), 'COD_DAY'].idxmax(), 'CARD']
print (card)
73306055
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much!
If I wanted to select only CARD and highest COD_DAY, how could I go about that?